# How to upload Android app to the market?

Tags: java, android, google-play

Hey I'am trying to aupload my app to the android market, I already have a developer account and I paid th 25$ and every thing but when I click to upload the app after it reaches 100% I get a message that "You need to use an SDK with a version number of 19 or lower."
how to solve this problem, or could someone explain to me what is the problem.

here is my manifest:

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18"
    android:maxSdkVersion="21" />
```

Comment: try changing maxSdkVersion to 19?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove maxsdkversion and keep targetsdkversion as 21

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You want to set the maxSdkVersion to nothing more than 19.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18"
    android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
```